# Using special character (apostrophe) in feature file table shell

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I'm writing a feature filein Selenium and 1 of the table shell has an apostrophe in it. Upon running the test case the Cucumber report came out as cannot translate the "'" as a valid character. Something like this:

```
Then user sees the following title
|Banker's report for this month|
```

How would I solve this? I tried

```
|Banker\'s report for this month|
```

but it wouldn't work

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the string in double quotes? It’s possible that that would work.

Comment: I tried    |" Banker\'s report for this month"|     but didn't work either

Comment: Try `|"""Banker's report for this month"""|`

Comment: 2 double quotes also didn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

You could just change the step definition to be something like

```
Then user sees the monthly bankers report
```

and have the step definition (which is code) specify the string.

Comment: I have to validate the exact title which displays on the webpage so this wouldn't work, cannot change the string in table cell. Thanks though

Comment: You still can do that in a step def there is no reason why you can't write the exact title you need in there.  Why do you have to have the title in the feature file? Who benefits? (those are questions for you, you don't need to answer them here)

Comment: This doesn't work for my use case either, since we are specifically trying to test whether passing in human names with apostrophes (ex: O'Shea) works.

Comment: Then perhaps you should write a scenario about names with apostrophe's e.g. `When I use a name with an apostrophe`, `Then I should see a name with an apostrophe`. Or alternatively test lower down the stack with unit tests, after all we know web browsers can display them and databases can store them, what exactly do you need to test, and why is it so important.